# Why is Azure SQL database so expensive?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

For a small personal coding project I recently created a SQL database in Azure. For the past weeks I have been hardly using the database, out of 2 GB available space I have been using only 13 MB.

However, the database costs me 6,70 EUR per day and I don't understand why this is the case. Read a few topics/posts stating that the costs with similar use should be around 5-7 EUR per month, not per day.

This is the configuration for the database:

- No elastic pool
- General purpose, Gen5, 2 vCores
- West Europe

Does anyone have an idea about what could be causing the costs per month to be so high?

Comment: Check out AWS, they have a free tier that you can use for 12 months or so. Not sure if it supports Azure Sql. As to getting an answer to your question that won't happen on [so] as it is very much off topic.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/ => $390.41Per month

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You choosed the General purpose, Gen5, 2 vCores price tier. Here is the cost every month:
[image]

This means that you must pay for it no matter how many space you used. As you said you just used only 13M. So you must change the Pricing tier.

What I suggest you is configure you database price to **Bacic** which only cost you **4.99 USD** per month. **Basic** price tier provides 5 DTUs and Max size 2GB for you.
[image]

You can change the price tier on the database overview site:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I guess this is what I need for my small development prototype. especially if I'm the only person using it, guess it will work just fine. I just got billed $200 for 1 vcore and that is not what I expected.

Comment: Be careful with the Basic tier. Never activate "Allow Azure Services". That means that any subscription from Azure, not only yours, can see your database. This means if I create a machine in Azure I could hit the port of your database. Hackers enjoy this.

Answer (score 8):

You're paying for the entire infrastructure is why.  It really only saves on upfront cost.  A dedicated server, Windows Server + SQL Server Web will run you, at least $5K. Performance wise, a dedicated server at a colo center will be a lot cheaper to run once you get the hardware.  I know, I've switched several companies off of Azure and, instead of paying $2500/mo, they pay $200/mo (after the server) for 4U at a colo + $100/mo basic maintenance and 1TB/mo bandwidth, so it adds up.  For example, I built 2 custom 1U servers (12 core/32GB) for $8500 and an opensource router for another $500 (pfSense), including OSes & SQL Server Web. Initial setup of both servers including SQL and the router for 16 IP Addresses was about $1K.  Total cost was $10K up front. The equivalent  horsepower and storage from Azure was $2500/mo. In 1 year on Azure it ran $30K!  1 year on colo (hosting + maintenance) was $13600, the following year was $3600. So far in 5 years, they saved ~$122,000.  There was only 15mins of downtime during the entire period.  Cloud hosting is a great idea, but it will never save you time nor money at the rates these company's charge. As far as downtime, I have been hosting for 2 decades and the worst downtime happened due to a network failure (that also took out multiple cloud providers) and it was 13 hours. The only other one was due to a fried router (about 3 hours).  Just my take on it - Cloud hosting is still way too expensive for what you actually get & redundancy is nice but you can buy a new server every 2 months for the price difference (just get good equipment w/redundant power supplies and hot swap drives - in a 55 degree colo center, failures are rare)

Comment: "but it will never save you time nor money at the rates these company's charge". It 100% saves time at the very least. Point and click vs contacting you for a physical set up. For a business that never needs to scale, your solution sounds pretty ideal. Cost of having full time employees servicing hardware for what *will be* sub-optimal services, plus engineers to maintain the DB, may end up costing more in the long run. Auto-scaling, less IT overhead, TONS of integrations with other services, plus refunds on downtime, is why you go with cloud. It's not for every business.

Comment: You still need an engineer(s) to configure everything. It takes about the same amount of time to do the myriad of configuring, testings, re-configuring and troubleshooting. So no, you're not really saving labor except, perhaps, manual labor of physically hooking everything up (but techs are cheap, Azure certified "engineers" are $80-$120/hr!)

Comment: For small businesses with 1 or 2 servers, going to the cloud is far more expensive, including the cost of the equipment (how often does a small biz server go down? pretty rare - out of 35 companies I've done work for in 20+ years, only once did a server mechanically go down - it was restored within an hour -  most of the time it's an application that failed or became corrupt - the Cloud won't save you from that!)

Answer (score 6):

It seems you don't know Azure offers a free tier. Please refer to Microsoft Azure SQL documentation for details on how to take advantage of the [free tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/free-offer?view=azuresql) that supports 100,000 vCore seconds of compute every month, free of charge.

In addition, Azure SQL Database offers a [Serverless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql) option that gets auto=paused when not in use, and it is billed per minutes instead of per hour.

Answer (score 2):

It's sure that Azure offers a `free tier` but still you can optimize it with very low cost if you use any `purchased plan.`

Here I provided some direction on the picture below that how to create **free** `App Service Plan`

[image: App Service Plan]

Now let's see how we can `optimize` the cost for `small database size` for your `purchased plan.`

1. Go to the option of `Create SQL Database`
2. Click on the link `Configure Database` as per the **below picture**

[image: Configure Database]

3. Then Select the `Basic option` under `DTU-Based` as per the **below picture**

[image: Basic option]

> As the above picture shows, the default selected option is `General Purpose` option under `VCore-Based` section, so it costs **$410** as it provides you **32 GB** database.

As `Basic option` is selected, so DB Size is changed into **2 GB** instead of **32 GB**, hence cost is changed into just **$5.64** instead of **$410**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it is a small project you can run it on Ubuntu Linux and it's $3.80/month or $0.0052/hour.
On top of this, you can install MySql or SQL Express. I personally find MySql easier to access/configure

Answer (score 0):

Got a bill of several thousands of euro's because the default pricing tier was set on several sql databases as "General purpose, Gen5, 2 vCores".

Note: the databases were almost empty and were not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Sep 2023 Azure SQL database has a lifetime free tier: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/new-azure-sql-database-free-offer/ :

*.. with a free amount of 100,000 vCore seconds of compute and 32 GB of storage plus 32 GB of backup storage every month, for the lifetime of your subscription*

*.. If you use up your free amount of 100,000 vCore seconds before the end of the month, you have two options: .. auto-pause and resume using it when the next month starts with a new free amount .. or .. keep using your database for additional charges..*

Check your estimated cost during setup, for me it was not $0 for the first chosen EU location, I had to change it to US to make it $0.

One of answers from 2019 already mentions "free tier" - that's not the same. That "free tier" was for 1 year, the new "free tier" is subscription lifetime.